# Array of functions in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function, return-value

How do I make a function that takes an input, for example `13`, and then executes all the functions in the array on that input and returns the output, which would be `4` in this case

```
array = [
  function(a){ return a * 2 },
  function(a){ return a + 1000},
  function(a){ return a % 7 }
]

function f(array){
  console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want `if (a === 13) return 4;` but I can't figure how you want to fit an array into this, and even less that array of functions you have. Mind rephrasing a bit?

Comment: I don't know why they closed this, it's clear what you want to do: `array.reduce((ret, fn) => fn(ret), 13)` will output `4`

Answer (score 1):

As Dave replied in the question, you could use `reduce` to make this happen:

```js
const runFunctionSequence = (sequence, input) => sequence.reduce((accumulatedOutput, fun) => fun(accumulatedOutput), input);

const arr = [
  function(a){ return a * 2 },
  function(a){ return a + 1000},
  function(a){ return a % 7 }
];

console.log(runFunctionSequence(arr, 13)); // -> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to run a number and each result through series of functions which are stored in an array.

```js
arr = [
  function(a){ return a * 2 },
  function(a){ return a + 1000},
  function(a){ return a % 7 }
]

function runAll(input){
  
  let output = input;
  for (let f of arr) {
    output = f(output)
  }
  
  return output;
}


console.log(runAll(13)) //4
```